# Bar Chart in Framework 4 - Update issue

Tags: .net, winforms, charts

So I'm trying to update dataPoints programmaticaly in a column chart but whenever I do this, the column chart displays empty columns where there IS a number greater than zero, and displays a zero otherwise.  Now the code below works for a pie chart but for some reason it does not work for the bar chart.

```
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(0).YValues.SetValue(countInstSubs, 0)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(1).YValues.SetValue(countPCLRetSubs, 0)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(2).YValues.SetValue(countSYNRetSubs, 0)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(3).YValues.SetValue(countPRESListSubs, 0)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(4).YValues.SetValue(countUSInstSubs, 0)
    barChart.Refresh()
```

When I use the designer to populate some static values, the chart displays those values.  But once I try to update them, I get a blank chart.  I have also tried clearing the series altogether and rebuilding it each time I want to change the graph but this did not work either.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Looks like if I completely dispose of the previous chart and rebuild everything it works; this means reallocating the chart, chart area, series, setting all properties, re-adding all datapoints and re-adding the resulting chart to the form.  This seems like way to much work compared to the easy update you get from a pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the axis scaling.  Once the values change, the axis doesn't automatically recalculate (bug in my opinion) so you have to do it manually.

```
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(0).SetValueY(countInstSubs)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(1).SetValueY(countPCLRetSubs)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(2).SetValueY(countSYNRetSubs)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(3).SetValueY(countPRESListSubs)
    barChart.Series(0).Points.Item(4).SetValueY(countUSInstSubs)
    barChart.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()
    barChart.Refresh()
```

This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good job on figuring out the solution.  You should mark it as the answer.

You can also add points dynamically with this syntax:

```
barChart.Series(0).Points.AddY(countInstSubs);
barChart.Series(0).Points.AddY(countPCLRetSubs);
barChart.Series(0).Points.AddY(countSYNRetSubs);
barChart.Series(0).Points.AddY(countPRESListSubs);
barChart.Series(0).Points.AddY(countUSInstSubs);
```

Comment: You can't mark your own post as 'the answer' until the next day (otherwise I would ;-)) If you want you can vote on my answer and I will mark it as correct tomorrow :-D  I figured that AddY would internally allocate another datapoint and append it to the existing datapoints.  This is not what I want.  I want the number of datapoints to remain the same and just update their values.